# Issue in displaying Piechart slices with different color

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I have created the `piechart` using `MPAndroidChart` as follows,

```
    List<PieEntry> yvalues = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
    yvalues.add(new PieEntry(1f,1));
    yvalues.add(new PieEntry(15f,2));
    yvalues.add(new PieEntry(15f,3));
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues,null);
    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
    dataSet.setColors(Color.rgb(34,140,0),Color.rgb(225,0,0),Color.BLUE);
    pieChart.setData(data);
```

The problem is, The first slice `color` is not displayed (changed as transparent) when app is launched. But the two other slices has the same `color` as I mentioned.I don't know what is wrong with that.

> I have used **com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0**
>
> Guide me friends. Thanks!!!

Comment: try to change version 3.0.0 to latest one 3.02. because this issues mention in git see that https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2754

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within the library. Change the first value to 2f and check. Now it's showing the color. Color is not showing for 1f. Try using this library
[hellocharts library](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android)